# Float string format

Tags: php, string, floating-point, printf

`%01.2f`

I know ".2" is the precision, but what does the 1st part mean - `%01` ?

I tried changing it to 05, 2 etc and the resulted string looks the same..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: you simply didn't try to change it to 020

Comment: Which numbers did you try with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how much spacing is there. It's back from printf in C. Looking up printf would give you more information. However, it's simple enough to explain here.

I am guessing that the reason it doesn't do anything is because HTML doesn't allow more than 1 consecutive space and so it doesn't show up but if you ran your PHP in a command line (it's possible) then you would see the spacing appear.

For instance in C (php is basically a C language for the web) you could say

```
printf("%20s %20s!", "Hello", "World");
```

And that would print out something like this

```
               Hello                World!
```

in normal html it should show as this (not in a 'code block') :                Hello                World!

^^ That is spaced the same in the code btw.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to print columns. For example, if you want to print into one column of 50 characters a number with 4 floating digits, and want to fill with 0s the beginning of the number , you use:

```
%050.4f
```

If you want to fill with spaces instead of 0s the beginning of the column, you use instead:

```
% 50.4f
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need the space there.  I'm actually not even *sure it will work* with the space.  `%50.4f` should be sufficient.

Comment: I use this syntax with python and C all the time.

Comment: @jedwards: The space is valid, per the 1999 C standard, section 7.19.6.1, paragraph 6, which lists the flag characters for output formats. A space indicates to prefix a space to the result if the first character of a signed conversion is not a sign or if a signed conversion results in no characters.

Comment: @ericpostpischil: Intersting find.  Considering we're talking about PHP though, [it turns out the space is not necessary](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).